# Deprecation notice: Obsolete Place IDs

Tags: plugins, google-places

I am setting up the plugin WP Google Review Slider, never thought it was so difficult!

I am getting error:

> Deprecation notice: Obsolete Place IDs

and I cannot find where to refresh or update the place ID.

In WP dashword within the plugin I added the API key and I have to add as well the place id, when I do I gett this error message:

> Google API Error: Wrong Key or Maps API not added. Due to recent changes by Google you must now add the Maps API to your existing API key in order to use the Location Lookup feature of the Google Places Widget.
> View documentation here

and when I go to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/place-id, in order to get the place id I get this one: "Deprecation notice: Obsolete Place IDs" and there is no way who to find how to solve it.

Comment: could please somebody help? thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**Strategy**

Call the Place details API to check if the place id is valid
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=ChIJDx2VxLa1j4AR--kx601BUbY&fields=place_id&key=<API_KEY>
(change "fields=place_id" to "field=" to see all fields)

It can result in following

1. Current google place id
2. Updated google place id
3. INVALID_REQUEST - (status code indicates that the specified place ID
   is not valid)
4. NOT_FOUND - (status code indicates that the specified place ID is
   obsolete. Id is obsolete if a business closes or moves to a new
   location) (in this case lat long may not be useful if a business
   moves to another location)

- Handling the above conditions

1. Do not do anything (in the future may check also the last time data
   is updated in DB to avoid frequent API calls)
2. Update the google place id inside DB and continue with the open map
3. Request the google details API with lat long to get a valid google
   place id
4. Request the google details API with a place name to get a valid
   google place id

Answer (score 0):

Refresh the place id via:

```
GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/output?place_id=<your_place_id>?fields=place_id
```

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/place-id#save-id):

> We recommend refreshing place IDs if they are more than 12 months old. You can refresh Place IDs free of charge, by making a Place Details request, specifying only the place_id field in the fields parameter. This will trigger the Places Details - ID Refresh SKU. However, this request might also return NOT_FOUND status code. One strategy is to store the original request that returned each place ID. If a place ID becomes invalid, you can re-issue that request to get fresh results. These results may or may not include the original place. The request is chargeable.